# Why can be Beta function formula used on divergent integrals as well?

Tags: integration, beta-function

Few days ago I came across this result:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{3\sin^2 x + 2\cos^3 x - 2}{\sin^4 x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{4}{3},$$
sure, you can show this result by a few number os annoying steps which include many trig identities, since *any* of the three summands alone is *divergent* (you have to not to separate the integrated function as a sum to the whole end).

On the other hand if you plainly use the known formula
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n-1} x \cos^{2m-1} x \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}B(n,m) = \frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(m)}{2\Gamma(n+m)},$$

you would get
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{3\sin^2 x + 2\cos^3 x - 2}{\sin^4 x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(0)}+\frac{2\Gamma\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}-\frac{2\Gamma\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}{\Gamma(-1)}\right) = \\
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\cdots}{\infty}+\frac{2\Gamma\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}-\frac{\cdots}{\infty}\right)= \frac{\Gamma\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)} = \frac{4}{3},$$

which is a *correct result*.

**MY QUESTION:** Why this method is even correct? Is it right that the divergent parts magically cancels? Or why this method yields a correct result?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem of convergence since, close to $x=0$, the integrand is
$$\frac{3}{4}+\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^4}{192}+O\left(x^6\right)$$

Comment: Yes, this is true, if the middle 2 is changed to any other number, the convergency disapears. However, that does not solve the problem of the credibility of this approach. Is convergency sufficient to treat the Beta approach diving infinities?